# Creating curved footer

Tags: css, footer

Is it possible to have the following image as a footer and have content sit correctly without having the image overlap the content

[bg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ic84.png)

Comment: It depends; what browsers do you need to support? https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path here's how it's done: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096136/how-should-i-convert-this-psd-to-html-css-banner/52096702

Comment: I had started off with making the footer as an image that can stretch on DT but it effects the content in the main by creating a huge white space. I was unsure of what route to go. Here's what I've tried so far.  https://codepen.io/conor-byrne/pen/gdWWZY

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside

Answer (score -2):

off course you can do that. by just adjust the layer which states as z-index in cascading style sheet.

img {position : absolute; z-index : -1;}